# Maven―loading properties no matter which phase the process begins

Tags: maven, properties

I would like to introduce the use of property files, using the [maven property plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/).

How can I integrate the plugin so that it reads the properties file no matter which with phase the process begins?

Means:

The `properties:read-project-properties` goal should be executed always a the very beginning of the build process, no matter if I call `mvn clean`, or `mvn compile`, or any other set of phases and goals to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `<executions>` tag for the plugin.  Look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html) for further information.    If you want plugin (mojo) to execute before everything else I suggest attaching to 'validate' or 'initialize' phase.